At a low level, how does CM108 fob modification work?
I have an elderly Kenwood RT (which I think predates packet radio).
I have it connected to a laptop (no mic input), so I added a modified "CM108 fob" device to it to give me bidirectional audio and PTT. Both aspects of it work fine on their own. I have audio OK for SSTV, "or" I can get PTT to work, but not both at the same time.
Hence the question. I have read that the CM108 GPIO pin actually goes high only when there is an attempt to output audio, and that this in-built vox is a feature of the CM108, which needs no additional software. Others, however, claim that there is an API call in (for example flrig) which can be used to pull the pin high independently of audio.
So, firstly, which is it? how does it actually work? Information is ... scant.
Secondly, I have a feeling both articles are working independently, but not together because (in my case) QSSTV is talking to the audio portion of the USB sound card whereas flrig is also trying to talk to it to get the PTT to activate. Is this a likely explanation?
Thanks.

The CM108 has no built-in VOX. The GPIO ports of the CM108 are accessed by the OS as a USB HID device.
Some ham radio applications (like fldigi, VARA, Dire Wolf etc.) can acces the GPIO (PTT) pin of the sound chip directly. For applications that can only do PTT by keying the RTS line of a (virtual) COM port use "CAT7200", a small tool written by J. Wiseman G8BPQ that is able to control the GPIO/PTT on the CM108. Additionally a virtual COM-port connection (e.g. com0com) between the application and CAT7200 is needed.
https://www.cantab.net/users/john.wiseman/Documents/CAT7200.html
https://com0com.sourceforge.net/

Do you suppose my issue was the fact that QSSTV and flrig were both trying to assess the USB sound card? If this is so, I can see why DireWolf, etc (programs written specifically with this mod in mind) will work, but I suspect that the CAT7200 tool might work standalone, but not in tandem with QSSTV.

I see no conflict between QSSTV and flrig accessing both the audio codec (audio device + GPIO/PTT device). Flrig being part of the fldigi package knows how to access PTT on the CM108, you just have to config QSSTV to make it talk to flrig. One option would be the XML-RPC interface. Enable the XML-RPC server in flrig (CAT settings) and the client in QSSTV (CAT config) and make sure to use the same port number. According to the QSSTV manual you may need to use an older version (< v1.3.4) of flrig. CAT7200 is for legacy ham radio apps that only support PTT through a real/virtual COM (RTS) port.

With my apologies if this is nothing more than a grammar point. I also see no problem with either program accessing both the facilities on the one card. My concern is that they're "both accessing" rather than "accessing both". Is it safe for two pieces of software to both access the CM108 at the same time? If I'm right, your suggestion is the same problem. Now I'd have QSSTV acecssing the audio of the sound board at the same time as CAT200 accesses the PTT of the sound board. Or does XMLRPC do the audio component as well as the PTT component? That seems like it would work.

Think of the CM108 chip as two completely separate devices (audio + GPIO). QSSTV is sending the audio directly to the audio device inside the CM108. The command to activate the PTT is going through the XML-RPC interface (similar to a CAT interface) to flrig which then toggles the actual PTT pin of the GPIO device inside the CM108. CAT7200 is able to do the same thing as flrig but uses a virtual COM port as connection to third party applications that do not support the more modern XML-RPC interface.

That leaves me stuck as to why either program can drive its particular feature but both (QSSTV and flrig) cannot drive their features (audio and PTT) at the same time. What a mystery. I ended up using the RTS port of an FTDI. It does annoy my having to use two USB ports.
